# Await socket.on('answerToRequest') possible with Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, backend

Is the following somehow possible?

```
async function doesSocketAgree(){
    socket.emit('doesOtherSocketAgree', otherSocketId);
    await socket.on('responseDoesSocketAgree', (answer)=>{
      console.log('answer');
});
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, but not that way. You'll have to wrap things in a promise so that you can "return" from your `await` once data comes in as part of your "on" handling:

```js
async function doesSocketAgree(){
  socket.emit('doesOtherSocketAgree', otherSocketId);
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    socket.on('responseDoesSocketAgree', answer => {
      resolve(answer);
    });
  });
}
```

And you *probably* want to remove that listener before you call `resolve()` so that it doesn't keep on triggering, because every time you call `doesSocketAgree()` you'd be adding a new listener to the "on:responseSocketAgree" pile. So that'll end up going wrong pretty quickly without cleanup.

On that note, you probably want to emit your "does it agree?" with a random token that your `on` handler can verify is the one that's scoped to the current function call, "because async".

Comment: Or he can/should use "acknowledgements" callbacks: https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements

Comment: You would need to remove your event listener after it fires, otherwise it would accumulate.

Comment: Right, so: as mentioned, before `resolve` gets called. But Marc's solution is better.

Answer (score 6):

In socket.io you can use "acknowledgements" callbacks:

```js
async function doesSocketAgree(){
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    socket.emit('doesOtherSocketAgree', otherSocketId, (answer) => {
      resolve(answer);
    });      
  });
}
```

https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements

So you can use a single `emit()` and can trigger a callback.
That has the advantage you dont have to deal with memory leaks from register an event listener every time you call this function.

Comment: This is likely the best way to do this.